# ajax load methoding with id stored in a js variable

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hello all. Can any one please tell me how do i load a `div` by [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) *load* method whose id is in a `javascript` variable? I mean that the id of the div is to be loaded is stored in a javascript variable ..

I can not put quotes around a `js` variable and the load method will not perform unless i have put quotes around the div id.

```
function formsubmitionbyajax(obj){
    // id of the div to be loaded is stored here. 
    // i donit know the value.  it can be anything 
    var divid=$(obj).attr("id"); 
    $.ajax({ type: 'post',
        url: 'home_formhandler1.php',
        data: currentform.serialize(),
        success: function() {
            $("#divid").load("home.php divid");
        }                   
    } );
}
```

this code is not working ..
i think i js is taking the variable `divid` as string..

Comment: Did you try `$("#"+ divid).load("home.php");`

Comment: is there any other way please help me

Comment: @user2701926 please add html. Better if you can have the issue on JSFiddle.

Comment: how should i add html there?? please tell me a bit more

Answer (score 0):

If your div is already passed in as `obj` you don't really need to use the ID at all. Here is how I would rewrite this:

```
function formsubmitionbyajax(obj){

   $.ajax({ type: 'post',
      url: 'home_formhandler1.php',
      data: currentform.serialize(),
      success: function() {
         $(obj).load("home.php");
      }                   
   });
}
```

By doing `$(obj)` you are basically accomplishing the same as by extracting the id of the div and then using that ID later on.